# Show that $F_r(x)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $r \ge 0$ and $x ∈ X$, define $F_r(x)$ $=\{y ∈ X:d(x,y) \le r\}$

Show that $F_r(x)$ is closed.

I know to show something is closed if it contains all of its limit points, but I don't know how to go about proving it.

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408309/when-the-set-of-r-far-interior-points-from-a-set-is-open/1408440#1408440) I proved that the distance function is continuous. The set $F_r(x)$ is closed being the preimage of the closed set $[0,r]$ under the continuous map $d(x,\cdot)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To show $F_{r}(x)$ is closed, you can show that $X - F_{r}(x)$ is open. So let $y \in X - F_{r}(x)$. Then $d(x,y) >r$. We can then pick $\epsilon >0$ such that the open ball $B(y,\epsilon)$ is contained in $X -F_{r}(x)$, completing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For fixed $x\in X$, show the function $g:X\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(y)=d(x,y)$ is continuous function, in fact Lipschitz continuous by triangle inequality of metric $d$.